# Totals show up in subform but not showing up in the form in Access 2013

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013, subforms

I am in access and I have a form that contains a subform. When I open the subform it has the totals on the bottom which I want. But in the form the subform does not have the totals? Do you guys have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Can you give an example? I know you can't post a picture yet.

Comment: It actually showed up but it just takes a while. Idk why since my computer is fast but they show up it just takes a while.